# Example value of Joda DateTime

Tags: java, datetime

I create list of object with example parameters and I cannot put example value of joda DateTime. Only value is accetable is "null". This is contructor:

```
public TestDTO(
            String name,
            String lastName,
            String country,
            String city,
            String age,
            DateTime startTime,
            DateTime endTime,
            boolean active)
            {
        this.name = name;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.country = country;
        this.city = city;
        this.age = age;
        this.startTime = startTime;
        this.endTime = endTime;
        this.active = active;
    }
```

and here I create list:

```
public List<TestDTO> getInitListTableItems(){

        List<TestDTO> list = new ArrayList<TestDTO>();
        list.add(new TestDTO("John", "Doe", "USA", "New York", "20", null, null, true));

        return list;
    }
```

When I put for example "(12/12/2011)" or "2011-12-12" and other insted "null" it return mistake and convert value to int or String type. What is the correct value of DataTime?

Comment: If you are using Java 8 (or 7) I suggest using the JSR 310 API which is based on JodaTime.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
DateTime.parse("2011-12-12")
```